# Best way to find the location of a specific file within a node dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to access a file contained within a node dependency.  Previously I was hardcoding access to this file in the form `require('../../node_modules/foo/bar.png')` however this path cannot be relied upon with npm v3 as the place in the node_modules folder hierarchy where a given dependency sits may change.  `require.resolve` doesn't seem to help me as it gives the main file within the dependency rather than just the folder of the dependency.

Comment: Why do you need to pull an asset from a dependency? Any cases that I can think of it would be better to either link to an image on their website or simply pull the image out and put it somewhere in your project.

Comment: Project A is a server package that is designed to set up a server and then serve project B.  Users should be able to install A globally and not have to worry about setting it up with B, hence shipping B as a dependency

Comment: Then project B should offer resources in some sane way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're writing both modules you can use __dirname from inside the dependency to get the path the module is running from:

```
//foo/index.js
module.exports.root = __dirname;
```

Then use that to serve the files:

```
//server.js
var assets = require('foo');
fs.readFile(assets.root + '/bar.png', function(){/*whatever*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/dive and assert every files.

```
dive(directory[, options], action[, complete]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A common solution I have found on github in various open source projects is to use [findup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/findup)/[findup-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/findup-sync), ie

```
var findup = require('findup-sync');
var filePath = findup('node_modules/foo/bar.png');
```